# How can I use StanfordNLP tools (POSTagger and Parser) with an already Tokenized file?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, pipeline

I have a tokenized file and I would like to use StanfordNLP to annotate it with POS and dependency parsing tags.
I am using a Python script with the following configuration:

```
config = {
'processors': 'pos,lemma,depparse',
'lang': 'de',
'pos_model_path': './de_gsd_models/de_gsd_tagger.pt',
'pos_pretrain_path': './de_gsd_models/de_gsd.pretrain.pt',
'lemma_model_path': './de_gsd_models/de_gsd_lemmatizer.pt',
'depparse_model_path': './de_gsd_models/de_gsd_parser.pt',
'depparse_pretrain_path': './de_gsd_models/de_gsd.pretrain.pt}'
```

`nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(**config)`

`doc = nlp(text)`

However, I receive the following message:

- missing: {'tokenize'}
  The processors list provided for this pipeline is invalid.  Please make sure all prerequisites are met for every processor.

Is it possible to skip the tokenization step using a Python script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `tokenize` processor and include the property `tokenize_pretokenized` set to `True`. This will assume the text is tokenized on whitespace and sentence split by newline. You can also past a list of lists of strings, each list representing a sentence, and the entries being the tokens.

This is explained here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/tokenize.html